# expected behaviour of function in dll file written in c and calling from cpp file

Tags: c++, c

I have written a  dll file in c and calling it from cpp but  i am not getting the expected behaviour please explain me how it works
my dll files (.c and .h)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if defined (WIN32)
#if defined(FUNCTIONS_STATIC)
#define FUNCTIONS_API
#else
#if defined(FUNCTIONS_EXPORTS)
#define FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#endif
#else
#define FUNCTIONS_API
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef MYMATHDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYMATHDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MYMATHDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.1415
MYMATHDLL_API double PowerOf3(double UserNumber);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**.c**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
double PowerOf3(double UserNumber)
{
    return UserNumber * UserNumber;
}
#endif
#ifndef __cplusplus
    double PowerOf3(double UserNumber)
    {
        return UserNumber ;
    }

#endif
```

i compiled above function as dll and using it in the cpp file

**.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>    
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "modell.h"
#include "modellfunktionen.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#include "MyMathDll.h"
}
#endif   
using namespace std;
typedef double(*MYFUN2)( double op);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   widepath ="C:\\Personal\\VB_practice\\MyMathDll\\x64\\Debug\\MyMathDll.dll";
    hMod = LoadLibraryA(widepath);
    //cout << widepath << endl;
    MYFUN2  pfun2 = (MYFUN2)GetProcAddress(hMod, "PowerOf3");
    cout << pfun2(10) << endl;
}
```

gives me result 10 but i expect it 100 as cplusplus is defined. Where am i getting it wrong.

Comment: That's not how the preprocessor works. The DLL is compiled by the C compiler, where `__cplusplus` is *not* defined. That your application using the DLL is made from C++ is totally irrelevant to and disconnected from the DLL and the sources used to create it.

Comment: I am also curious about the *real* problem behind a solution like this? What leads you to ask this question? What is the problem, that makes you *think* you need to handle C and C++ differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because those defines are checked at compile time, you compiled it as C code, so compiler detected you're not using C++ so

```
#ifndef cplusplus
```

fired, non matching preprocesor directives are 'invisible' for compiler at compile time, just like you removed them manually from code, they don't work like runtime if

Comment: is there any way to check at  run time.. as i have a dll file which contains c functions and prototypes (ex. fopen, printf) they doesnt work while i call these from cpp at run time

Comment: @SaiKrishna No, there no way of knowing at run-time. The application and the DLL are totally separated from each other. It's better to think of the DLL as a separate program, when it comes to things like these. And the application could be written is just about any language, besides C or C++, making your assumption and wanted behavior flawed.

Comment: best shot would be to make different dlls for c and c++, and give them different names, and e.g. load library_c.dll in C app and library_cpp.dll in C++ app, to have both C and C++ functions included in DLL you need to link it to C and C++ runtimes, other thing I can think of you can make some kind of singleton for your library and get your functions from there, like: in c++: Library_CPP lib = GetCppLibrary();, and in c: Library lib = GetCLibrary();, they would only differ in name and implementation of algorithms, but would serve same end purpose, and you could pick if you want C or CPP func

Comment: @SaiKrishna A DLL does not (at least normally) contain standard library functions, such as `fopen` and `printf`. What *exactly* are you trying to do, and how? (Post a new question, and please be more specific than "doesn't work".)

Comment: @molbdnilo Basically i have a very big .c file which reads the data from text file and process the data and write to another text file. Now to run tests on .c file i have third party application which accepts only .cpp file, instead of converting the entire .c file to .cpp i am creating a dll from .c and calling it from .cpp.